# Bitfinex API -> retrieve funding earnings for custom period

Tags: api, cryptography, bitfinex

I am trying to retrieve my funding profit of the previous day via the Bitfinex API.

But all I find is this API which only returns the profit of the last 30 days summed up (funding_profit_30d):

```
https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/summary
```

Anybody found anything else? Bitfinex Support is also not helpful...

Comment: Hi, did you figure it out? There is a method called mytrades_funding but it does *not* look like the one we are looking for: https://bitfinex.readme.io/v1/reference#rest-auth-mytrades-funding

I'm also looking for a way to get the earnings from offering fundings...